# Workflow Error : Workflow cancled show error coercion failed input cannot be null for this coercion In SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

When I selected field is empty and save I get this error.

```
Workflow Error : Workflow canceled show error coercion failed input cannot be null for this coercion In SP 2013
```

I know when I select the return type as `string` it work but this is not my solution.
I want to select return type as `semi delimited`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a workflow string variable then create a condition that only updates the variable if the value of the field is "not empty" then you can set the variable to the value of the field (comma delimited) and use that variable in an email.
I face same issue.
http://praveenbattula.blogspot.ca/2010/02/sharepoint-exception-coercion-failed_15.html

Comment: Ok i will try this solutions.